# how to display a specific page for 3 times and then display the another page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

designing an app in which i need to display a page as pop up that i did. Now as per the need when someone is opening the app on his device this page should appear but only 3 times (that means if user will open the app 3 times this page should come up) but for the 4 th time instead of this page another view needs to open. How to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Store a counter in `NSUserDefaults` and when the counter exceeds 3, don't show the popup again.

Comment: can u tell me in brief hw i can use counter.?

Comment: what he meant by counter is to store a number in user defaults.

Comment: if its `nil` store `1`, if its `1` or `2` increment it, if its `3` then don't show whatever you're not supposed to show.

Answer (score 0):

use a counter in applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
...

NSInteger c = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"StartCount"];
if(c < 3) //0,1,2
{
    //do stuff
}
else
{
    //other stuff
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:++c forKey:@"StartCount"];
```